# evento onchange en IE cuando se modifica valor de input programaticamente

Tags: javascript, html, eventos, internet-explorer

He notado que en diferentes versiones de Internet Explorer el evento `onchange` no es capturado cuando el valor de un input es alterado por una función js, comportamiento que no ocurre con otros navegadores como Mozilla o Chrome.

Investigando un poco encontré que no está garantizado el correcto funcionamiento de `onchange` en IE cuando se altera el valor mediante js:

- [onchange not fired on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876152/onchange-not-firing-in-ie)
- [onchange not fired when autocomplete is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343192/why-does-the-javascript-onchange-event-not-fire-if-autocomplete-is-on)

Ejemplo de como reproducirlo:

```js
function onchangeRequest(){
  console.log('onchange fired');
}

function changeValue (input){
        input.value +=  "add"
 }
```

```html
<h4> Al perder el foco no invoca onchangeRequest() </h4>

<input id="valueInput" placeholder= "Insert value here"  onkeyup="changeValue(this);" onchange="onchangeRequest();" />

<h4> Al perder el foco invoca onchangeRequest() </h4>

<input id="valueInput" placeholder= "Insert value here"  onchange="onchangeRequest();" />
```

No he encontrado una explicación convincente de los motivos por los cuales IE no resuelve correctamente esas situaciones aunque existen alternativas para obtener el mismo comportamiento, como implementar el `onchange` mediante `onfocs` y `onblur` guardando el valor anterior del input y chequeando si hubieron cambios, quisiera conocer las razones por las cuales se da este comportamiento.

Es esto un error conocido con el cual tenemos que lidiar e implementar otras alternativas como la que mencione anteriormente? Existe alguna referencia oficial donde se explicite que IE no garantiza el correcto comportamiento de onchange?

Comment: `onchange` sólo se es activado al perder el focus mediante una política específica, en IE solo funciona a través del mouse

Comment: A que te refieres con "una política específica"? En el ejemplo que he dado, en el primer input, el onchange no se dispara al perder el foco, ya sea mediante mouse click o teclado.

Comment: La solución propuesta como onfocus + onblur es la más eficiente para lidiar con onchange, otros emplean onclick para el fix pero por obvias razones no funcionaría cuando se perdie el focus mediante el teclado

Comment: ["the onchange event fire when leaving the textbox with a mouseclick, but not by pressing the tab key"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510907/help-ie9-onchange-event-doesnt-fire-when-value-is-modified-by-an-onkeydown-s)

Comment: Política se refiere al manejo y captura de eventos, su forma de ser activados y la forma de propagarlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto a tu pregunta:

> ¿Existe alguna referencia oficial donde se explicite que IE no garantiza el correcto comportamiento de onchange?

No sé si calificaría ese comportamiento como incorrecto. Durante muchos años Microsoft siguió una estrategia según la cual no seguía en su navegador los estándares marcados por W3C, pero el comportamiento es el correcto según la especificación propia de IE.

Finalmente Microsoft ha entendido también que ésta era una estrategia equivocada y ahora sí que sigue los estándares de W3C pero en las versiones antiguas de sus navegadores persiste por supuesto este problema.

La documentación oficial es la propia de Microsoft para IE:

[change | onchange event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912(VS.85).aspx)